# Windows 8 Embedded Standard - Obtain WMV Codecs?

Tags: windows-8, codec, embedded, wmv

I'm evaluating Windows 8 Embedded Standard to be used for media playback. Following creating an installation with every single component enabled I find that the OS is unable to play back WMV files, the codec is missing.

The playback of WMV files is crucial.

I'm confused as to why they would be omitted.

Searching MSDN I see references too:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj963524(v=winembedded.81).aspx
Which indicate a License is required, but beyond that no more information.

Reviewing and following guide for Win7e (http://andrewmorgan.ie/2012/02/07/adding-windows-media-player-codecs-to-windows-thin-pc/) doesn't help as the CAB's are not compatible.

Clearly I'm missing something, do the codecs not come with Win8e ? Can anyone advise what steps I need to take to obtain and install these codecs?

Comment: I just tried WMV playback on a WES8 image in a VM and works fine. Do you have a special image?

Comment: Not that I'm aware, we just downloaded it from the MSDN site.

Comment: Also interested in this. Did you find any info? There is also this site which is not much help: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windowsmedia-licensing